# How to transfer large amount of data from aws S3 bucket to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We need to transfer nearly 1000GB data from AWS S3 bucket to another. It's a one time transfer. I have found several solutions for that. One is same region replication. Another solution is for transfer data using AWS CLI. What can be the best solution for this task?

Comment: Are the buckets in the same region?

Comment: yes @Paolo.Buckets in the same region

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to migrate data that already exists on the source bucket, you should use a one-time [S3 batch replication job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-batch-replication-batch.html).

You might also find [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-replicate-existing-objects-with-amazon-s3-batch-replication/) post useful.